How to stop Windows from decreasing processor speed when not connected to remote desktop
We use a windows 11 machine as scientific workstation at work. When I'm connected via remote desktop simulations I run in R are fast but when I'm not connected one simulation takes about 3 times longer.
The power-plan is already set to performance. Which settings can I tweak to stop the computer from slowing down while not connected?
I read the output of powercfg /? but I didn't quite figure out if the settings there are what I need.

I don't use RDP very much if ever, but I suspect this is going to be because the session is "idle" in the sense that you disconnected but have not logged out, and RDP server/service has downgraded priority for running the process. So probably not powercfg.

You mean that your computer is three-times slower for some operations than the remote computer to which you RDP to do remotely the same operation? Or do you mean that you run it locally in both cases and it's faster if the RDP connection is just present and nothing is running in the remote session?

so it sounds like you are assuming that something like CPU throttling (the stuff youd configure in power management) is the cause of the issue, but do not yet have proof that that is the case. personally I'd suspect that there is other software on the system that is supposed to run only when the system is idle, so logging CPU/Process activity while not actively logged in would be where I'd start. Perfmon or CPUMon would probably be where I'd start.

Does it behave the same way if you just lock the remote desktop or minimize it for a while? Windows doesn't care whether you are connected to the RDP session or not, and power settings for performance only change based on battery/plugged-in status. Some background jobs like search indexing can kick off when the system is idle for some time, so if your sim uses a lot of disk IO, you could see hefty performance dips

When just minimizing the remote desktop Sims run on normal speed. The Sims have some disk I/O but I don't think it's the cause of the issue. When reconnecring the processor load increases and the Sims get faster again.

how are you running the simulations? how are you determining that "the processor load increases"? I believe you need to run some performance monitoring software in a session that is not tied to your RDP session, so you can record what happens when you are not RDPd in.

Hi, I'm running the simulations by sourcing an R file in Rstudio desktop. I know that processor load increases because the graphs of performance monitor increase after re-connecting and because the simulations are getting faster again.

ok that implies that the issue is not CPU throttling. your CPU Usage % won't change as the result of a frequency change (using 100% CPU @ 1GHz will display the same as 100% @ 4GHz), so that implies that the issue is likely thread-scheduling or an issue with the applications approach to threading. Does RStudio give you any options for configuring threading parameters, like max threads? counter-intuitively, it may run faster with fewer threads.
